# Actionscript 2.0 flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have written this basic button code a thousand times before on CS5. Now I bought CS6 and this simple AS2 code is not working.

On the first frame I made a movieClip symbol and added in its actions :

```
on(release){
   gotoAndPlay(2);
  }
```

---

Then I made a new layer on top, I typed :

```
stop();
```

in the frame's action.

**Problem:** From the second frame the animation was supposed to start, but it didn't work and stayed on the first frame even when I clicked the button several times. How to fix this issue?

I have even tried :

```
rooting on(release)
{ _.root.gotoAndPlay(2); }
```

Comment: i have even tried rooting      on(release){                                                                                                                                                     _.root.gotoAndPlay(2);                                                                                                      }

Comment: check if it is ActionScript2 or ActionScript3 project

Comment: Why AS2? Stop while you still can.

Comment: It is actionscript 2.0.

Comment: Organis . Do u mean that I should not use As2. If that's your point then I totally agree but still I have always used As2 so I still love coding on it. Please help me finding the solution of this problem

Comment: Please use the **@** symbol to notify a specific person. I think @Organis meant use your time & energy to learn AS3 while you can (more capability, more flexible, more opportunities). AS2 stopped in 2007 but AS3 features are updated regularly to this day.

Comment: Try spending one day of your free time to make an AS3 project that makes a movieClip object (its timeline) go to frame 2. Never make the entire `stage` go to a different frame cos there is no code there so you constantly re-define everything. A stage-sized movieClip can be used like a container or "stage" for content...

Comment: @VC.One, thanks. What I mean, AS2 is ~10 years since obsolete. It is slower, it is far less capable, and in terms of programming AS3 is far more straight as a language, as well as there are not many people out there who remembers what is the exact addressing context of script in on () {} and onClipEvent () {} clauses.

Comment: @StephenNollan use trace(this); (or maybe trace(_this);) anywhere in the code to understand which MovieClip addressing context this code is bound to and then navigate with ._parent or .ChildInstanceName addressing to get the wanted context.

Comment: If I remember correctly, on () {} clause is bound to the container context of the object this script is attached to, be it MovieClip or Button.

Comment: thank you @Organis

Comment: And indeed yes i m 19 so i guess i have time to experiment new possibilities, i will practice on as3 henceforth. I hope to hear from you guys again while practicing AS3 cause i m sure i ll have many more doubts there.

Comment: @StephenNollan Good. There's nothing AS3 cannot do that AS2 can. There are plenty AS2 cannot do AS3 can.